# Values of a field disappear when editing (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is the form that proccesses two models: *Post* and *Tag* both have a   `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with each other. The Tag model has an attribute called `:name` and the Post model has an attr_accessor called `:tag_name` (so that the auto-completion can work):

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.cktext_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_name %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_name

  attr_accessor :tag_name

  def tag!(tags)
    tags = tags.split(" ").map do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
    end
    self.tags << tags
  end
end
```

post controller:

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end

    @post.tag!(params[:post][:tag_name])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    @post.tag!(params[:post][:tag_name])
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

This field that uses the **rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem** do store the values I enter. But when I click edit the field is blank but the strange thing is that I can enter more text and click update:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :"data-delimiter" => ' ' %>
```

Any suggestions in order to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the autocomplete gem, but have you tried manually setting the value in the `autocomplete_field`?